# Testing Sidekiq workers using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq

How do i test the following line of code invokes 'perform' in 5 mins using rspec?

```
CustomSidekiqWorker.perform_in(5.minutes, parameter1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've set Sidekiq to use inline processing while runnings tests like so:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

Then the following should work in your specs:

```
expect(CustomSideWorker).to receive(:perform_in).with(5.minutes, parameter1)
```